# 'tanh' activation function has a strange output

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence

Using keras, I am getting a bad output from 'tanh' activation function. It supposed to give floats in range of [-1, 1], but I am getting output in range of [-10, 10]. What is the problem here? Thanks.

This is the model structure:

```
def create_generator(dim=NOISE_DIM, optimizer=GEN_OPTIMIZER):
generator = Sequential()

# Starting size
d = 4
generator.add(Dense(d*d*256, kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(0, 0.02), input_dim=dim))
generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
# 4x4x256
generator.add(Reshape((d, d, 256)))

# 8x8x128
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(0, 0.02)))
generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

# 16x16*128
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=4, padding='same', kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(0, 0.02)))
generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

# 64x64x128
generator.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(0, 0.02)))
generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

# 64x64x3
generator.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='tanh', kernel_initializer=RandomNormal(0, 0.02)))

generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
return generator
```

Example of output:

```
      ...

  [[-1.31739629e-03 -9.18284408e-04 -8.88809795e-04]
   [ 5.84446476e-04  1.48985186e-03 -8.59379943e-04]
   [ 1.28604515e-04 -2.04776973e-03 -6.45169814e-04]
   ...
   [-1.10365311e-03  4.84788558e-04 -1.07841019e-03]
   [-1.61853048e-03  2.44487106e-04 -2.03575328e-04]
   [-1.30298943e-03  1.26789114e-03 -6.83081045e-04]]

  [[-3.66462773e-04 -2.87405564e-04 -3.52254836e-04]
   [-7.28385407e-04  3.68534849e-04  9.69631219e-05]
   [-1.90682462e-04  6.41632010e-04 -1.34694483e-03]
   ...
   [-1.31186307e-03 -2.17378582e-03  1.81564025e-03]
   [-1.35134242e-03  4.37091017e-04  3.16255668e-04]
   [-1.82685023e-03 -4.86125617e-04  5.67631563e-04]]

  [[-7.98511028e-04 -8.82301887e-04 -1.65282312e-04]
   [-1.44832267e-03 -6.28359208e-04 -9.62364720e-04]
   [-2.95009726e-04  1.77540205e-04 -1.48139487e-04]
   ...
   [-6.42001803e-04  4.31965804e-04  6.40484213e-04]
   [-1.32995576e-03  8.39460583e-04 -3.31234711e-04]
   [ 5.94170066e-04  3.08730640e-04  8.76617676e-04]]]]
```

Comment: What value in the output is in the range [-10, 10]?

Comment: They are in scientific notation...

Comment: It's mysterious float format. Does these numbers after hyphen indicates leading zeros?

Comment: oh! It makes sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So what you are encountering here is the scientific notation.

In Python the scientfic notation is just a formatting and the value is just a float, so you can do this:

```
    >>> print(-1.31739629e-03)
-0.00131739629
```

Since the numbers after e is negative move the decimal point left. This means that none of you outputs are smaller than -1 or bigger than 1.